# Google API multiple scopes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scope, google-api

I want to use multiple scopes in the Google API JavaScript.
What I'm trying to do is to get the user Email & Name.

The Name i can get from the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

And the Email i can get from the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

But how I can use them both in the same application?

My code is:

```
scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';

    gapi.signin.render('StartGoogleBtn', {
      'callback': 'onSignInCallback',
      'clientid': clientId,
      'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
      'scope': scopes
    });
```

What scopes should be? Thanks :)

Answer (score 28):

Just guessing, but try space delimited with double-quotes surrounding it. That's what OAuth 2 calls for and when I wrote the code for the client I made it automatically deal with that scenario correctly. I assume it'd just get passed through by the command.That's work for me.

```
scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
```

Comment: it doesnt work with my code

Answer (score 3):

I'll preface my answer by saying that I haven't used the Javascript version. I'm using the Java library, which lets me set the scopes by passing a list of strings containing the scopes I want.

```
List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
        DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP, //https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
        DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER,  //https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
        DriveScopes.DRIVE                      //https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
        );

credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12File)
                .setServiceAccountUser(adminUser).build();
```

Assuming the Javascript library works similarly to the Java one, you should be able to add multiple scopes by making your `scopes` variable an array of Strings.

Comment: Was looking for this solution in Java and this worked perfectly for me. Thanks a bunch, especially, when the google documentation is so poor.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you exactly right the scope step by step this is the format you should follow while writing the scope on Google app script in appscript.json

{
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"]
}